# Chrome extension. Как вставить на страницу javascript чтобы он выполнился раньше всех скриптов на странице?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "binary_pool",
"version": "1.0",
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": [
    "*://*/*"
  ],
  "js": [
    "js/jquery.js",
    "js/content.js"
  ],
  "run_at": "document_end"
}
],
"web_accessible_resources": [
   "js/content_real.js"
],
"background": {
   "scripts": [
     "js/background.js"
 ]
 },
 "permissions": [
  "*://*/*"
 ],
 "browser_action": {
 "default_title": "binary_pool",
 "default_popup": "popup.html"
 }
}
```

content.js

```
let script = document.createElement('script');

script.src = chrome.extension.getURL('js/content_real.js');

$('head').prepend(script);
script.remove();
```

content_real.js загружается позднее чем скрипты в head. Как сделать чтобы он загружался раньше всех скриптов?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Через интервал

```
const interval = setInterval(() => {
if ($('*').is('head')) {
    let script = document.createElement('script');

    script.src = chrome.extension.getURL('js/content_real.js');

    $('head').prepend(script);
    script.remove();

    clearInterval(interval);
}
}, 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run_at = "document_start"

```
var s = document.createElement ("script");
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL ("MyPwnCode.js");
s.async = false;
document.documentElement.appendChild (s);
```

Answer (score 0):

run_at = **document_start**

Читаем документацию: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

А если скрипту понадобится конкретный элемент (который на тот момент еще не будет построен), то ожидать его можно с помощью рекурсивного setTimeout.

Comment: Сделал run_at = document_start, проверяю существование элемента через интервал. Скрипты в head грузятся быстрее чем мой скрипт.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос. Посмотри код

Comment: Что за script.remove();? Перепиши без jq. Но вообще тут нет гарантий. 100% способа нет. API ограниченное.